# Do we have a "first conditional" in this text?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

The great king, they said, having respect to the mutability of human affairs, was desirous of dealing mercifully with the Romans, and would allow the escape of the remnant which was left of their army, if the Caesar and his advisers accepted the conditions that he required.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the "if" statement is "open" and not "remote", that is, from their perspective at the time, it was possible that "the Caesar" would accept his requirements, or not.

If they accepted his conditions, he would allow their escape.

Do you understand the meaning of the sentence? That's as important as classifying it in an educational category (first conditional).

Comment: Yes, I understand that's meaning. thank you for your beneficial and instructive helps.